# Image Resolution degrading when georeferencing

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, image, resolution

I have a scan of a historical map in pdf. I converted it in to png as well as tif and then georeferenced it. However, as soon as I load the image (both png and tif) in to the georeferencing tool the resolution is degrading. Does somebody know why this is happening and how to prevent it? I use QGIS.

Comment: Are you using a CRS that fits the georeferenced imagery?

Comment: Does the map look better when you zoom close enough for inserting the ground control points?

Comment: Maybe posting a screenshot or the resulting georeferenced image could help understanding the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can directly load your PDF into the Georeferencer canvas. QGIS uses the GDAL config option `GDAL_PDF_DPI` to set the resolution of the PDF. The default value is **150**. You can increase this value with an System environment variable (i.e. *GDAL_PDF_DPI=300*): <kbd>Settings</kbd>><kbd>Options...</kbd>><kbd>System</kbd>>*Environment*

[image]

Comment: My PDF has a good resolution, therefore I dont need to improve it. I need to convert it in to png and then georeference it, so for me only the resolution of the png/tif is of relevance.